# 2D struct array: swap row and col?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I want to swap the entire column and row of a 2D struct array.

With this code I can swap rows:

```
#define N 9 
typedef struct { 
    char number;
    bool editable; 
} FIELD;

int main(){
FIELD **f = (FIELD **) malloc(N * sizeof(FIELD *));
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    f[i] = (FIELD *) malloc(N * sizeof(FIELD)); 
}

//example: swap row 0 and row 8
FIELD *tmp;
tmp = f[0];
f[0] = f[8];
f[8] = tmp;
}
```

But how can I swap an entire column?

Comment: Please either use C or C++ tag, depending on what language you are coding for. Do not use both, since they are different languages, and would potentially have different solutions.

Comment: You'll have to swap each individual value in the column to achieve the goal

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.

Comment: OT: regarding: `FIELD **f = (FIELD **) malloc(N * sizeof(FIELD *));` and similar statements: 1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  2)  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output to `stderr` your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  3) before exiting the program, call `free()` for each memory allocation, to avoid a memory leak

Comment: Since `free()` properly handles a parameter that contains `NULL`, much better to make the initial allocation using `calloc()` so do not need to track the number of successful allocations when freeing the allocations

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a pointer swap for columns.   You will have to do it algorithmically.

Answer (score 1):

To swap an entire column you should iterate over all rows:

```
//example: swap column 0 and column 8
FIELD tmp;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    tmp = f[i][0];
    f[i][0] = f[i][8]
    f[i][8] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap the columns elementwise. The layout of your array lets you exchange rows by swapping the pointers, but the column elements are each on a separate row.

```c
void swap_cols (FIELD **f, int cola, int colb) {
    for (int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
        FIELD tmp = f[i][cola];
        f[i][cola] = f[i][colb];
        f[i][colb] = tmp;
    }
}
```